# How can I have my discrete graphics card always enabled?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I'm using Bumblebee and I have to run optirun (program name) in order to get my graphics card working. how can I make it work for everything from the start? I tried nvidia-prime but it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your BIOS settings and disable the iGPU.  If the hardware cannot be found, no modules will be loaded except the discrete GPU, resulting in the GPU to be used for everything!

Low quality reviewers: That's it! ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response I tried that but i couldn't find it in my laptops bios maybe because it's a laptop what I did was re-installed my ubuntu and this time Nvida prime work's fine. I maybe messed up with something I shouldn't before.

Comment: My laptop has "Hybrid - discrete - on-board" in it's advanced BIOS settings..  Glad you've found a solution!